# Grab values between delimiters in Perl from chomped line

Tags: regex, perl, chomp

I am trying to grab the values between two delimiters in Perl using regex. I am opening a file and using chomp to go through the file line by line. Example of how the file looks:

```
"This is <tag> an </tag> example
of the <tag> file </tag> that I
am <tag> trying </tag> to <tag> parse </tag>"
```

I am able to get the first couple of words: "an", "file", but on the third line I can only get "trying" and not "parse". This is the code I am trying to use:

```
while (chomp($line = <$filename>)){
   ($tag) = $line =~ m/<tag>(.*?)<\/tag>/;
   push(@tagarray, $tag);
}
```

I suspect this has something to do with `chomp` but don't see how to parse the file differently.

Comment: I normally use [HTML::TreeBuilder](http://search.cpan.org/~kentnl/HTML-Tree-5.07/lib/HTML/TreeBuilder.pm) (for HTML)

Comment: If you're processing HTML or XML then you should use a library specifically for that purpose, rather than trying to create your own using regex patterns.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> I suspect this has something to do with chomp

No. It is because you are capturing only one value and assigning it to a scalar.

Make the regex global (`/g`) and store the results in an array.

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use v5.10;

my $line = "am <tag> trying </tag> to <tag> parse </tag>";
my @tags;
(@tags) = $line =~ m/<tag>(.*?)<\/tag>/g;
say join ",", @tags;
```

Answer (score 8):

You need to modify the regex to grab multiple matches:

```
my @tags = $line =~ m/<tag>(.*?)<\/tag>/g;
```

You may be better off using an HTML parser to perform this operation. Parsing HTML with regular expressions is [fraught with peril](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/1021515). For example, take a look at [HTML::TagParser](http://search.cpan.org/~kawasaki/HTML-TagParser-0.20/lib/HTML/TagParser.pm):

```
my $html = HTML::TagParser->new(<<'EOF');
This is <tag> an </tag> example
of the <tag> file </tag> that I
am <tag> trying </tag> to <tag> parse </tag>
EOF

my @tags = $html->getElementsByTagName('tag');
my @tagarray = map { $_->innerText() } @tags;
```